# How to copy and save the file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Using VB.Net

I want to copy the txt file from one location to another location.

```
textbox1.text = Source file directory
textbox2.text = destination file directory
```

For Example

```
textbox1.text = "C:\1.txt"
textbox2.text = "d:\"
```

I want to copy 1.txt to d drive.

How to do this.

Need Sample Code Help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx) method.

```
File.Copy(source, destination)
```

Or, if a file already exists in the destination location, specify a boolean value indicating whether or not to overwrite,

```
File.Copy(source, destination, overwrite)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straight forward:

```
File.Copy(textbox1.Text, Path.Combine(textbox2.Text, Path.GetFileName(textbox1.Text)))
```

Comment: +1: i dont see a filename at textbox2.text(plus the absence of Camelcasing for text at textbox2) :)

Comment: @naveen: Right... as it's just a path you have to get the file name from the source. I added that.